# How can I improve this code for Project Euler 7?

Tags: java, primes

By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.

What is the 10 001st prime number?

My solution:

```
public class Prime_Number {

    public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
        if ((n > 2 && n % 2 == 0) || (n > 3 && n % 3 == 0) || (n > 5 && n % 5 == 0) || n == 0 || n == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        int prime = 0;
        while (prime <= 10001) {
            if (isPrime(count) == true) {
                prime++;
                if (prime == 10001) {
                    System.out.println(count + " is a prime number" + "(" + prime + ")");
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not give a correct answer. Please help me to upgrade my code. For instance, program defines a 91 as a prime number, but it is not a prime number. How to improve it?

Comment: 91 = 7 * 13 -- that should show you why your current method of testing primality will not scale.

Comment: I've solved this problem by implementing the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Erastosthenes). It gave me a clear understanding of the problem and a possible solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to test the number against every prime less than its square root to ensure it is prime.

You're only testing against 2,3 and 5.

Because storing all the primes is not always space-feasable, a common technique is to test for 2, and then test all odd numbers starting at 3. This requires a loop.

consider:

```
boolean isPrime(long n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
    if (n < 9) return true;
    if (n % 3 == 0) return false;
    long max = (long)(Math.sqrt(n + 0.0)) + 1;
    for (int i = 5; i <= max; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
        if (n % (i + 2) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can optimize that by including a check for `number % 3 == 0 -> false`, then unrolling the loop starting with 11 (increase by 6) and checking for `mod i` and  `mod (i+2)`. I'm so free and include the optimizations for fun :)

Comment: @Voo:  That should be `int i = 5` instead of `i = 11`, right?

Comment: @Austin Doh yeah obviously - don't ask me how the hell that happened. Embarrassing really :(

Comment: @glowcoder - You can use `i * i <= n` as the condition for ending the loop:)

Comment: @Petar Yeah he can, but why would you want to do that? Computing the upper limit once is much more effective than that for larger numbers (a sqrt computation isn't that much more expensive than a multiplication with SSE)

Comment: @Voo I like it. It looks like it will end up checking a little bit past the max in some cases, but that's easily made up for by skipping as much as it does. And you were right about `i = 11`, since it will test 5 and 7 which are both covered by the `if(n < 9)` clause.

Comment: @glow Yeah that was probably my thinking as well, but that's comparing apples to oranges: We still have to check % 5 and % 7 for values larger 10. E.g.: If we'd start with 11 25 would suddenly be prime. And yes we may have one additional modulo operation (could be avoided but I agree not worth the effort) - but I just like it as an example how with some clever math even a real simple algorithm can be improved quite a bit.. but as usual clever == more bugs as I impressively proved there ;)

Comment: @PetarMinchev, @Voo Correct me if i'm wrong, but with `i*i <= n` An integer overflow might occur. And then you have an infinite loop. Say `n ~ Long.MAX_VALUE`, i'm not sure really.

Comment: @PetarMinchev, I don't think that'll still work. `for(long i = (long)(Math.sqrt(Long.MAX_VALUE) - 10) ; i*i < Long.MAX_VALUE ; i++)` this is an infinite loop.

Comment: I mean it should work if` n` is not so large that the next square overflows the `long`.

Comment: @Petar so you then also have to put in there `i*i < n && i < Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is rather clunky. Plus you have a multiply and extra comparison on every iteration instead of just a comparison. That's marginal, I'd take the extra multiply for a massive boost to readability, but that actually detracts from readability..

Comment: @glowcoder - Agreed:) I just wanted to share another option, although it is quick and dirty.

Comment: Why do you increment the for loop by 6?

Answer (score 4):

A number `p` is prime if it only divides by itself and 1. You are checking only for divison by `2`, `3` and `5`. This is not enough. Check for every number till `p / 2`, or better till `sqrt(p)`.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution checks only the odd numbers to be prime, but it counts `2` as prime from the beginning:

```
public class A {

    static int N = 10001;

    private static boolean isOddPrime(long x) {

        for ( int i = 3 ; i*i <= x ; i+=2 ) {
            if ( x % i == 0 ) {
                return false;
            }               
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int x;
        int i = 2;      // 3 is the 2nd prime number
        for ( x = 3 ; ; x+=2 ) {
            if ( isOddPrime(x) ) {              
                if ( i == N )
                    break;
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x);

        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time: " + (stop - start) / 1000000 + " ms");
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
104743
Time: 61 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment, but I just joined.

You don't have to check every number between 1 and a numbers square root for potential divisors, you just have to check all previous primes (assuming you start at 1 and iterate up), as any other divisor that is not prime will itself be divisible by a prime of a lower value. the higher the number of primes, the more checks against non prime numbers this saves. the example is in C# but that's more to demonstrate the concept.

```
    //store found primes here, for checking subsequent primes
    private static List<long> Primes;
    private static bool IsPrime(long number)
    {
        //no number will have a larger divisor withou some smaller divisor
        var maxPrime = Math.Sqrt(number);

        // takes the list of primes less than the square root and 
        //     checks to see if all of that list is not evenly 
        //     divisible into {number}
        var isPrime = Primes
            .TakeWhile(prime => !(prime > maxPrime))
            .All(prime => number % prime != 0);
        if (isPrime)
            Primes.Add(number);
        return isPrime;
    }

    private static long GetNthPrime(int n)
    {
        //reset primes list to prevent persistence
        Primes = new List<long> { 2, 3, 5, 7 };

        //prime in starting set
        if (Primes.Count >= n)
        {
            return Primes[n - 1];
        }

        //iterate by 6 to avoid all divisiors of 2 and 3 
        //  (also have to check i + 2 for this to work)
        //  similar to incrementing by 2 but skips every third increment 
        //  starting with the second, as that is divisible by 3
        for (long i = 11; i < long.MaxValue; i += 6)
        {
            // only check count if is prime
            if ((IsPrime(i) && Primes.Count >= n) || (IsPrime(i + 2) && Primes.Count >= n))
            {
                break;
            };
        }
        //return end of list
        return Primes[n - 1];
    }
```